# Encrypting plainText files and Decrypting them in Java with a Symmetric Key

Tags: java

I would like to encrypt a file using a symmetric key and decrypt it using the game key in java without losing data, I tried an encryption of a 56 byte file and the resultant file was 10 bytes which makes me think I'm going wrong somewhere.

Are there any tutorials on how to encrypt and decrypt files in java using a symmetric key? (and how to get said key?)

Comment: yes, there are many such tutorials (and i bet google knows about most of them).

Comment: I'd in particular recommend the works on Wikipedia -- a number of good, well-written articles there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short nice tutorial: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/symmetric.shtml

Here is a related question: [Java using AES 256 and 128 Symmetric-key encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538485/java-using-aes-256-and-128-symmetric-key-encryption)

Hope it'll help.