# Decryption of AES encrypted field in java

Tags: java, encryption

I tried to encrypt a field with java, but i cannot decrypt it back.

I'm not sending data, I just want it to be encrypted upon insertion and decrypted when retrieving.

I used this code but decryption doesn't work.

```
public void setkey() throws Exception {
    byte[] key1 = new String("abcd").getBytes("UTF-8"); // some logic will replace "abcd"
     MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
     key1 = messageDigest.digest(key1);
     key1 = Arrays.copyOf(key1,16);
     key = key1;
     //this key must be the same when encrypting and decrypting, right?
}

@Override
public String encryptField(Myclass myClass) throws Exception {

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
    String encryptedField = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(myClass.myField.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    myClass.setMyField(encryptedField);
    save(myClass);

    return encryptedField;
    //this looks OK, and gives me 24 character string.
}


@Override
public String decryptVoucher(Myclass myClass) throws Exception {

    String skey = key.toString();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
    byte[] decryptedField = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(yClass.myField.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    // decryptedField.toString() is not as same as original data...
    return decryptedField.toString();
}
```

ps : I already searched and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538485/java-using-aes-256-and-128-symmetric-key-encryption) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption/992413#992413), in fact I'm here with their help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the `toString` method on a byte array. `toString` gives you a String representation of the array object; it does not attempt to convert the contents of the array into a String. The output you're seeing is something along the lines of "[B@798b429b", right?

To convert your decrypted bytes into a String object use `new String(decryptedField, "UTF-8")`. That will correctly convert the bytes into characters.

Remember that Java has no way of knowing that the byte array contains data that represents characters. The `toString` method on the `Array` class returns a description of the array, not its contents. It uses the default `toString` implementation, which is:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

(from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

In this case, the class name is "[B" meaning "array of bytes".